# Discord.py editing channel by word that is in the name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making statistics bot, and i have a problem, with voice channel containing member count. I want to make bot update name of that channel, `on_member_join`, `on_member_remove` and when user use command `refresh` but i tried many times at different ways, and it stil don't work, i want to make him edit channel that contains in name "Members:" but i can `get` channel at most with constant name. Is there any way to `get` channel by containing "Members:"?

Okay, i tried Łukasz's code, but it still don't changes the channel name. My code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(600, 1200))
    guild = member.guild
    channels = [c for c in guild.channels if "Members:" in c.name.lower()]
    for channel in channels:
        await channel.edit(f"Members: {member.guild.member_count}")

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(600, 1200))
    guild = member.guild
    channels = [c for c in guild.channels if "Members:" in c.name.lower()]
    for channel in channels:
        await channel.edit(name=f"Members: {member.guild.member_count}")

@bot.command()
async def refresh(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Starting refreshing members count voice channel.')
    guild = ctx.guild
    channels = [c for c in guild.channels if "Members:" in c.name.lower()]
    for channel in channels:
        await channel.edit(f"Members: {ctx.guild.member_count}")
        await ctx.send(':thumbsup:')
```

And my channel screenshots (maybe it will be important):
[image]

[image]

## Can you please tell me why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `in` keyword, e.g

```py
>>> "members:" in "whatever members: something"
True
```

To get all channels that contain the word `members:`

```py
guild = # Any `discord.Guild` instance
channels = []

for c in guild.channels: # You can also use the `Guild.text_channels` or `Guild.voice_channels` attributes
    if if "members:" in c.name.lower():
        channels.append(c)
```

If you want a one-liner:

```py
guild = # Any `discord.Guild` instance
channels = [c for c in guild.channels if "members:" in c.name.lower()]
```

Then you can loop through every channel and edit it:

```py
for channel in channels:
    await channel.edit(**kwargs)
```

*Note: There's a heavy ratelimit for editing channels (2 requests per 10 minutes per channel iirc) you should use this wisely*

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20channels#discord.Guild.channels)
- [`GuildChannel.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20edit#discord.TextChannel.edit)

Comment: Thanks, but it still not works, bot isn't changing channel name. I even tried to enable Members Intents. I updated my question a little bit.

Comment: Yes, the list comprehension must have the `Members:` string in lowercase `members:` like in my code, you're comparing a string starting with capital with a string that's all in lowercase, that will always be False, e.g `"Members:" in "whatever members:"` => `False`, but `"members:" in "whatever members:"` => `True`

Comment: Ok, thanks i tried using lowercase, and still nothing.

Comment: what do you mean by still nothing? Any errors? Try priting the variables and tell me the result, I cant help you if you tell me that nothing happens dude